# Why I see so much code duplication in Linq in Reflector?

Tags: .net, linq, code-duplication

**Edit**: I made a mistake in my original question. It should be about methods **Last** and **LastOrDefault** (or **Single** and **SingleOrDefault**, or **First** and **FirstOrDefault** - plenty of them!).

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377864/was-is-the-performance-of-the-last-extension-method-for-listt), I opened Reflector and looked at code of

```
Enumerable.Last<T>(this collection)
```

Then I jumped to code of

```
Enumerable.LastOrDefault<T>(this collection)
```

and I saw exactly the same piece of code (about 20 lines) differing in only one last line (first method returns default(T), second throws exception).

My question is why it is so? Why guys in Microsoft allow duplication of non-trivial pieces of code inside .Net framework? Don't they have code review?

Comment: interesting, but no real question....

Comment: Also, Last(collection, predicate) has complexity of O(N) but that's probably topic for another discussion.

Comment: I think it is a real question.  Maybe there's some good reason why it is that way?

Comment: I believe `Enumerable.Last<t>` must be in O(N) because `IEnumerator<T>` can only be traversed sequentially starting at the first element. There is no O(1) method to get the last element.

Comment: I can see the methods differ significantly. What are you talking about?

Comment: **@bcat**: If the IEnumerable<> is an IList<>, it's possible to directly get the last element. This is only possible, though, if there's no predicate. Interestingly, the framework does exactly this.

Comment: IEnumerables are not limited to being ILists, e.g., a generator. Last() is not only O(n); it can be undecidable.

Comment: @jpbochi: Really? Cool, the framework is smarter than I thought!

Comment: I meant Last and LastOrDefault. Thanks for spotting a bug in my question - fixed now!

Comment: If the static type of the inner expression `x` is `IEnumerable<T>`, then `x.Last()` is O(n). If the static type of the inner expression is `IList<T>`, then `x.Last()` is O(1).

Comment: Even with predicate it's possible to get O(1) (depends on predicate and collection, of course) by iterating from back to front and returning the first matching element.

Comment: @Konstantin - back to front and returning first matching element - O(n). Worst case you go through the whole input.

Comment: @Kobi: Although technically still O(n), Konstantin's suggestion would have better performance than the current framework implementation in every situation except the worst-case. Worst-case performance would be the same as the framework implementation's best-case performance (ie, iterating through every item in the collection).

Answer (score 4):

In fact, they are not quite the same. The first is like this:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");

    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0) return list[count - 1];
    } else {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                TSource current;
                do { current = enumerator.Current;}
                while (enumerator.MoveNext());

                return current;
            }
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

And the other is like this:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");

    TSource last = default(TSource);
    bool foundOne = false;
    foreach (TSource value in source) {
        if (predicate(value)) {
            last = value;
            foundOne = true;
        }
    }
    if (!foundOne) throw Error.NoMatch();
    return last;
}
```

PS.: I hope I'm not breaking any copyrights now. :S

Comment: I meant Last and LastOrDefault. Thanks for spotting a bug in my question!

Comment: Considering the update, I see your point. The methods could be easily rewritten to avoid duplication. As for the reason they chosen not to do it, I have no idea. :S