# List not inheriting an IEnumerable extension method

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

I have the following code that creates an extension to an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```cs
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779135/1180926
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
  //.......
}
```

When I try to apply this to a list:

```cs
public static void RemoveTwo(List<string> strList)
{
    strList = strList.SkipLast(2);
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

But `List<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` ([src](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)), so shouldn't it also inherit its extension methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a list from the `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public static void RemoveTwo(List<string> strList)
{
    strList = strList.SkipLast(2).ToList();
}
```

Your extension returns `IEnumerable<string>` which is not a `List<string>`. However, if you want to modify `strList` you have to use methods of `Lists` like `Remove` that modify the original collection or you have to return the new list.

Instead of `SkipLast` you should use [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) if you want to change the original collection without returning a new list.

```
public static void RemoveTwo(List<string> strList)
{
    if(strList.Count > 0)
        strList.RemoveAt(strList.Count-1);
    if(strList.Count > 0)
        strList.RemoveAt(strList.Count-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue lies not in the invocation of the extension method (which works as is), but in the assignment of its `IEnumerable<string>` return value to a `List<string>` variable. For the sake of demonstrating, the following code would <strike>work</strike> compile fine (but do nothing):

```
public static void RemoveTwo(List<string> strList)
{
    strList.SkipLast(2);
}
```

Comment: Compiles but does nothing to the list, have a look at the comments on newstackexinst. answer

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is assigning **back** to the list the `IEnumerable<string>` return value. You **can't** do that, as even though all `List<T>`s are also `IEnumerable<T>`, the reverse is **not** true. What you need to do is *add* a `ToList()` at the end of the `SkipLast` call:

```
public static List<string> RemoveTwo(List<string> strList)
{
    return strList.SkipLast(2).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You got tripped up by New-Memberese again :). Your code does nothing to the original list, to make your code work you would need to pass strList in by `ref`.

Comment: Yes, you are re-assinging it back to the local variable `strList`, however the list that was passed in to the `RemoveTwo` function will not be modifed. You either need to pass the list in as a `ref` so the original list will be updated when you re-assign it or return the new list you generated as a return value.