# Remove last row from DataGridView row count

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, foreach, rowcount

I've create a `foreach loop` in C#. I'm trying to loop trough all the rows except for the last one, which is automatically added. Since the cells contains no values I'm getting a NullException.

**Important:** Setting AllowUsersToAddRows to false is not an option as this function is required.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in VRFileDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
```

I'm not trying to fix met `NullReferenceException`, I want to know how to perform a loop trough all rows except for the last automatically added row.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I fixed it by setting `VRFileDataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` before the loop and setting `VRFileDataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = true;` after the loop.

Probably not the best solution, but i works fine.

Answer (score 2):

consider using `for` loop instead of `foreach`

`VRFileDataGrid.Rows.Count - 1` means all rows except the last one

```
for(int r = 0; r < VRFileDataGrid.Rows.Count - 1; r++)
{
   DataGridViewRow row = VRFileDataGrid.Rows[r];
   Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You could also do something with the enumerable, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779328/1264905. This would still enable you to use foreach.

Comment: @molnargab, i think such solution is an overkill here; row count is known, the problem is to exclude the last row. but yes, it also should solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The auto-added last row will have its `IsNewRow` property set to `true`. You can simply skip over it:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in VRFileDataGrid.Rows)
{
    if (row.IsNewRow)
        continue;

    Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
```