# How efficient are chained LINQ statements?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have a case where I want to iterate all but the last 2 elements of a collection.

Let's say I do it a weird way like `x.Reverse().Skip(2).Reverse()`.

Will each LINQ operation generate effectively a nested iterator or cause enumeration, etc or is it smarter than that? What happens under the hood in this sort of case?

---

*Clarification: this is just one example of chained LINQ statements you might see, where a developer favours short powerful code without thinking too hard about performance - maybe they are a Computer Science student and this seems the 'cleverest' solution. I am not asking how to solve this particular example*

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer your question?

Comment: `Reverse` has to iterate the entire collection.  Depending on the underlying type `Count` might not have to iterate the entire collection.

Comment: What is the type of underlying source collection `x`? Which .NET version are you targeting so far?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `Count()`?

Comment: Any chance you could just use [`SkipLast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast) and just let the implementation handle the query optimization?

Comment: Unless the collection is very large, I would write the code in the way that is easiest to understand. But if you are worried about microoptimizing, or just curious how it all works, you can always look at the [reference source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs).

Comment: You may use [`SkipLast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=netcore-3.1) method, which was added starting from .NET Core 2.x

Comment: Or you can use the `SkipLast` in MoreLinq if you're still on .Net Framework

Comment: @juharr I believe `List<T>.Count` is O(1), not sure about the others.

Comment: @RoadRunner `Count()` takes advantage of anything that implements `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` to use the `Count` property which would almost always be O(1).

Comment: @juharr Yeah that would make sense. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Actually `Reverse` also takes advantage of anything that is `ICollection<T>` by using it's `CopyTo` go get the values into a buffer array to iterate backwards over, so the double `Reverse` on a `ICollection<T>` might not be that bad, but definitely has more overhead (especially in memory usage).

Comment: @juharr I had figured it would do deferred execution and just iterate backwards where possible. Not the case? This is the kind fo thing the question is here to ask. You see people chaining LINQ for short powerful functionality but it's not very clear how performant it is

Comment: `SkipLast` is a nice addition to Core though not available to me - but the question is not meant to be that specific.

Comment: It's important to understand what each Linq method does.  Most like `Select` and `Where` can yeild results as they iterate their source.  But you have to be aware of things like `Reverse` or `OrderBy`, or even `GroupBy` that have to iterate the entire source before they can even begin to yield results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off yes that is creating a "iterator" and does not actually do any iterating until you materialized the query in a `foreach` or by calling `ToList` on it.  When you do that the number of iterations that occur are based on the underlying type.  `Reverse` will create a buffer array for whatever source you give it and iterate over it backwards.  If the source is `ICollection<T>` then it will use its `CopyTo` method to populate the array which should usually result in a single bulk copy of contiguous data in constant time.  If it's not a `ICollection<T>` then it will iterate the source into the buffer and then iterate over it backwards.  With that in mind here's what happens for your specific query when you iterate.

First the last `Reverse` will start iterating its source (which is not an `ICollection<T>`).

Then the `Skip` will start iterating its source

Then the first Reverse will either do a `CopyTo` if its source is a `ICollection<T>` or it will iterate the source into a buffer array that it resizes as needed.

Then the first Reverse will iterate over its buffer array backwards

Then the Skip will take the results skipping the first two and yielding the rest

Then the last Reverse will take the result and add them to its buffer array and resize it as needed.

Finally the last Reverse will iterate the buffer array backwards.

So if you're dealing with a `ICollecion<T>` that's one `CopyTo` and then 1 iteration of all of the values and then 1 iteration of all but 2 of the values.  If it's not a `ICollection<T>` that's basically 3 iterations of the values (really the last iteration is of all but 2).  And either way it's also using two intermediate arrays in the process.

And to prove that the query does no iterations until you materialize it you can check out this example

```
void Main()
{
    var query = MyValues().Reverse().Skip(2).Reverse();
    Console.WriteLine($"After query before materialization");
    var results = query.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
}

public IEnumerable<int> MyValues()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"yielding {i}");
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Which produces the output

```
After query before materialization
yielding 0
yielding 1
yielding 2
yielding 3
yielding 4
yielding 5
yielding 6
yielding 7
yielding 8
yielding 9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

When compared to the other example you had `x.Take(x.Count() - 2)`, that will iterate the source before you materialize it once for the `Count` (unless it's `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` in which case it will just use the `Count` property) then it will iterate it again when you materialize it.

Here's the same example with the different code and the resulting output.

```
void Main()
{
    var x = MyValues();
    var query = x.Take(x.Count() - 2);
    Console.WriteLine($"After query before materialization");
    var results = query.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
}

public IEnumerable<int> MyValues()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"yielding {i}");
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

With the output

```
yielding 0
yielding 1
yielding 2
yielding 3
yielding 4
yielding 5
yielding 6
yielding 7
yielding 8
yielding 9
After query before materialization
yielding 0
yielding 1
yielding 2
yielding 3
yielding 4
yielding 5
yielding 6
yielding 7
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

So which one is better is completely dependent on the source.  For a `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` the `Take` and `Count` would be preferred (unless the source might change between when the query is created and when it is materialized), but if it's neither of those you might prefer the double `Reverse` to avoid iterating the source twice (especially if the source can change between when you create the query and actually materialize it as the size might change as well), but that has to be weighted against the increase in total iterations done and memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Most LINQ operation do not produce separate nested iteration. Though `Count()` has to iterate thru complete sequence.

As for the content of your question, please refer to: [How to take all but the last element in a sequence using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779129/how-to-take-all-but-the-last-element-in-a-sequence-using-linq)

Comment: `Count` does have a few optimizations, based on detecting the underlying type, where it doesn't actually have to iterate through the entire sequence. Here is the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b,references) for reference.

Comment: The content of my question is not how to take all but the last elements. That is just an example. The question is about how chained LINQ operations actually _work_

Comment: If you believe the question to be the same as another question, you should be voting to close the question as a duplicate, not answering it...

Comment: @Mr.Boy If you really want to understand how LINQ works under the hood, you should check the reference source for [`Enumerable`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs) as that is where the majority of it is implemented.

Comment: Every question about .Net can be answered "read the source"... not a particularly helpful answer :) I've edited my question to try and make it a bit clearer

Comment: Fully explaining LINQ is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to know how a LINQ statement works, how efficient it is, it might be a good idea to look at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) (google: reference source Enumerable reverse)

Here you'll find that as soon as you start enumerating your sequence (this is: use a non-deferred method = use a LINQ method that does not return IEnumerable, or use foreach), the first Reverse will enumerate your complete sequence once, but it in a buffer, and start iteratingbackwards from the last element.

Your skip(2) will only enumerate 2 elements.

The 2nd Reverse will make a new Buffer, containing these two elements and start iterating backwards: so in your original sequence forwards.

If you look what happens: the elements of your original sequence are put in a buffer, the last and the pre-last elements are put in a second buffer. This second buffer is iterated: pre-last then last element.

So every element it iterated once, the last two elements are iterated once again. If iterating is a lot of work, consider creating a List, then take the last two elements. This will iterate your elements only once.

> If you have other LINQ statements of which you wonder how it is done, lool at the source code