# Last() with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq-to-objects

How *effective* is using `Last()` for arrays?

```
var array = new[] { ... };
var last = array.Last(); // or array[array.Length - 1]
```

In [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,75722fd194dc2e0e) it only distinguish `IList<T>`, so is that true what `Last()` will **enumerate a complete array** to return last item? Funny stuff is [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx) without a single note.

Comment: `T[]` implements `IList<T>` (See even this response to the question linked by fubo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1377891/613130)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array does implement `IList<T>`:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var list = (IList<int>)array;
```

So `Last` will not enumerate all array but instead will do `array[array.Length - 1]` (with a check that array is not empty of course - it which case it will throw).