# LINQ SkipWhile - Take at least one

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `IEnumerable` of values on which I need to skip certain elements at the beginning, I'm using `SkipWhile` for this. However, I definitely need at least one element (given the sequence even contains at least one element to begin with). If all elements pass the predicate (i.e. all Elements are skipped) I'd like to get only the last element. Is this somehow possible without expensive tricks like

```
items.SkipWhile(/* my condition */).FallbackIfEmpty(items.Last())
```

(Expensive as in: It needs to iterate the sequence twice, I'd like to prevent that)

Comment: what is `items`?  It it's a `List<T>`, [.Last() already runs in O(1) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377864/what-is-the-performance-of-the-last-extension-method-for-listt), and you're only iterating over your list once

Comment: And if you want this to work with any predicate, you can't get around iterating over your list at least once.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is any less expensive but you could use IEnumerable<T>.Reverse() and then walk through it normally, returning the first match.

Comment: @SamIam Unfortunately it's not, it gets filtered heavily beforehands and kept as IEnumerable.

Comment: @tkausl So, What Is it?  Where does it come from?  `IEnumerable` is an interface, it being an IEnumerable could mean anything

Comment: @SamIam It begins as a list but gets passed through `Select`, `Take` and `Where`, so not sure with which class exactly I'm ending with, its essentially a pipeline of operations. My objective is to not evaluate anything beforehand, only once I really iterate the resulting sequence, and only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ does not offer a built-in method for this, but you can write your own extension.

This implementation is lifted, for the most part, from Microsoft's [reference code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipWhileOrLast<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
) {
    bool yielding = false;
    TSource last = default(TSource);
    bool lastIsAssigned = false;
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (!yielding && !predicate(element)) {
            yielding = true;
        }
        if (yielding) {
            yield return element;
        }
        lastIsAssigned = true;
        last = element;
    }
    if (!yielding && lastIsAssigned) {
        yield return last;
    }
}
```